# Redirect HTTPS to HTP on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

I have an account with a webhost that uses Apache servers.  The webhost's file structure uses subfolders for secondary domains of the primary account domain.

What do I need to add to this .htaccess file to redirect if someone types https:mysubdomain in the browser URL.  I want to redirect from https to http, ie. http:mysubdomain.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myseconddomain\.myprimarydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myseconddomain\.myprimarydomain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mysedonddomain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Edit Update:
Thank you for suggestions.  The approach of modifying the .htaccess file for the subdomain in the subfolder didn't work, even after clearing browser cache.  What about modifying the .htaccess for the maindomain.  I tried this but it didn't work either.  Maybe my syntax?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https:\/\/myseconddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^www.myseonddomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I have spoken at length with the webhost, Hostmonster, and all they could tell me was that the SSL certificate was working "correctly" - even thought it is associating with unrelated domain names that are not supposed to have any  certificate.  I guess that is what User82217 was saying, there is no other way than to purchase a wildcard SSL?

Edit Update:  I tried putting this in the .htaccess of the maindomain and the seconddomain and nothing works to redirect from https to http when the user types https:// in front of mysecondubdomain.com in the URL

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Anybody got any more ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: There are lots of http/https redirect questions, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.htaccess%5D+is%3Aq+redirect+https+to+http, most are the other way round, but you'll get the idea. Also look at [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and variable `HTTPS`.

Comment: Note that if you don't have an SSL cert installed on `mysubdomain` then the user will still obviously get the browser warning about an invalid certificate _before_ your redirect occurs.

Comment: The syntax you've used in the second part of your updated question is completely wrong?! (But you used the correct syntax in the first part?)

Answer (score 0):

To force HTTPs to HTTP then you can use the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
#Force HTTP on everything
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

You didn't specifiy if you wanted to remove `www` or not, but on the assumption that you do, you can also remove that by including the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
```

Therefore checking if `www` is in the URL or not, so altogether using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Although the OP is wanting to only redirect subdomains of the maindomain (that map to secondary domains on the account) to the secondary domain. (However, this won't be possible unless they have a wildcard SSL cert on the maindomain.)

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not redirecting.  I tried the codelines on two different subdomains,  Each has its own .htaccess. I got the browser warning about invalid security certificate, but after confirming, no redirect occurred.  In the URL I tried both with and without the www.